# Array is masked as string in "IN" statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, doctrine, dbal

When using this DQL

```
$getImages = $em->createQuery('SELECT stuff
    FROM MyBundle:MyModelClass
    WHERE model.id NOT IN (:hide)')
->setParameter('hide', join(',', $hide), 'array');
```

The resulting SQL will be mapped to:

```
SELECT stuff FROM mymodelclass WHERE model.id NOT IN ('1,2,3');
```

Which is obviously wrong as it should be

```
SELECT stuff FROM mymodelclass WHERE model.id NOT IN (1,2,3);
```

So the query is fulfilled correclty. How can I tell doctrine to map the array without escaping it to a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [manual](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#list-of-parameters-conversion)

`$stmt = $conn->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id IN (?)',
    array(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)),
    array(\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY)
);`